# Why does stability drop whenever I get a new monarch?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

Playing as France with a 1444 start, it seems that I keep losing stability every time my monarch dies, even if the heir has good stats and seemingly nothing is wrong.

It seems like I would spend a lot of admin power if I had to re-up stability every time there's a new king. Isn't there a way to avoid this? Why does it happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Clyde as already pointed, it's just a game mechanic that is unavoidable and pointed out here http://www.eu4wiki.com/Ruler#Deaths

If you don't have any good modifiers for stability cost then I'd avoid using your ruler (or heir) as a general, unless they're terrible, like Castille's starting ruler and heir.

A further piece of advice is to get a stability cost modifier.  My usual go to for this is under religious ideas(http://www.eu4wiki.com/Idea_groups#Religious) as Church Attendance Day.

If you want to avoid this entirely, switch to a republic.  They won't suffer the stability hit and you'll also always get a leader with average stats(e.g. 1/4/1).  There are events for switching for certain nations or you can let legitimacy fall low enough to spawn rebels.

Comment: Wrong about the legitimacy thing - while a republic can fall into a monarchy with low republican tradition, the reverse is not true for a monarchy - the only ways to become a republic from a non-republic are:
~
1) Form Netherlands and pick Dutch Republic in the event.
~
2) Pick either Trade+Economic or Aristo+Influence, stay below 20 provinces and use the decision once both groups are complete.
~
3) Get revolutionary rebels from events associated with the Religious and Aristocratic idea groups and let them win - you will become an oligarchic republic as a result.

Comment: Dutch republic is awesome, but the other two ways are either cripplingly bad or unreliable. Basically, the best way to become a republic is to start as one.

Comment: A monarchy can be forced into a republic by letting rebels force their demands, hence why you should let your legitimacy fall as it will encourage the types of rebels that enforce that demand, such as revolutionaries or peasants(or atleast this was the case in previous versions).

Comment: There are no unrest-based rebels that force a republic on you - only event-based ones, thus intentionally forcing unrest on yourself is unnecessary.

Peasants only cause LA to rise and revolutionaries are purely event-based - it is impossible to get them without an event that spawns them.

Answer (score 18):

It's just part of the game and is unavoidable.  It's one of the things you'll need to direct a portion of your admin power towards.

In real life, in a hereditary monarchy (or any authoritarian form of government), transitions of power were in fact destabalizing.  You never know who might get ideas about taking power, and even if there's no question about who the new monarch is going to be, there's going to be an huge scramble among advisors, nobles, etc. to see who will have real influence in the new administration.